# Как выделить строку в QTextEdit по клику мыши?

Tags: c++, qt

Т.е. нужно кликнуть мышью в список в QTextEdit, получить номер строки, куда был клик, и выделить эту строку.
А ещё желательно выделять строку нужного номера программно, без клика мышью.

Answer (score 1):

Для отлавливания клика, ва понадобится установить соответствующий eventFilter, в котором просто выделить строку под курсором:

```
QTextCursor c = ui->textEdit->textCursor();
c.select(QTextCursor::LineUnderCursor);
ui->textEdit->setTextCursor(c);
```

что касается выбора определенной строки:

```
void MainWindow::selectLine(int line)
{
    QTextCursor c = ui->textEdit->textCursor(); //получили текстовый курсор
    c.movePosition(QTextCursor::Start); // переместили в начало документа
    c.movePosition(QTextCursor::Down,QTextCursor::MoveAnchor,line);// сместили  на line позиций вниз
    c.select(QTextCursor::LineUnderCursor); // выделили строку под курсором
    ui->textEdit->setTextCursor(c); // установили курсор назад
}
```